# Java SQL error 1064

Tags: java, sql

I'm having trouble with some simple code but can't figure out what exactly I am doing wrong. 
Following is my code:

```
String userName = "username";
        String password = "password";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://computername/proejct";
        Connection conn=null;
        String value="some_value";

        try 
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

            String query1=  "SELECT * FROM table  WHERE column_Name=?";
            PreparedStatement psmt1 = conn.prepareStatement(query1);
            psmt1.setString(1, value);

            Boolean count=psmt1.execute(query1);
            if(count==false)
            {
                //do something
            }
            psmt1.close();

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
  com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@5f989f84: SELECT * FROM source2  WHERE File_Name='Messages.java'
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor3.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2562)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2512)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:781)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:624)
    at SearchAndUpdate.recursiveUpdate(SearchAndUpdate.java:98)
    at SearchAndUpdate.recursiveUpdate(SearchAndUpdate.java:115)
    at SearchAndUpdate.recursiveUpdate(SearchAndUpdate.java:115)
    at SearchAndUpdate.recursiveUpdate(SearchAndUpdate.java:115)
    at SearchAndUpdate.recursiveUpdate(SearchAndUpdate.java:115)
    at SearchAndUpdate.recursiveUpdate(SearchAndUpdate.java:115)
    at SearchAndUpdate.recursiveUpdate(SearchAndUpdate.java:115)
    at SearchAndUpdate.recursiveUpdate(SearchAndUpdate.java:115)
    at SearchAndUpdate.recursiveUpdate(SearchAndUpdate.java:115)
    at SearchAndUpdate.recursiveTraversal(SearchAndUpdate.java:55)
    at SearchAndUpdate.main(SearchAndUpdate.java:40)
```

Am I doing something wrong with the preparedstements ?

I printed out the prepare-statement, this is what it looks like:
SELECT * FROM source2  WHERE column_Name='Messages.java'

Comment: Is this `String query1=  "SELECT * FROM table  WHERE column_Name=?";` the statement in your actual class? Your error message `SELECT * FROM source2  WHERE File_Name='Messages.java'` shows a different statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this line:

```
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

it looks like you statement is not being prepared. The `?` is being sent to MySQL.

I think this:

```
Boolean count=psmt1.execute(query1);
```

should be (edit)

```
ResultSet count=psmt1.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Also just want to add your variable shouldn't be a boolean it should be a ResultSet since you are doing a select statement. I dont know if that would cause an error but it should be taken into consideration